# How to print the data from Datagrid in .net Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am displaying the data from the MS access database in the DataGrid of a .net windows desktop application. Now I want to print the data of the DataGrid or want to take the Printout of the data of DataGrid only not of whole page. Can anybody help me to sort out my problem?

Please advice the answer in C# language.

Comment: What exactly you want to print , All the columns int he gridview or just the selected one??

Comment: I am displaying the required data only. So want to print whole data of the DataGried.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Since you're printing a WinForms DataGrid I suggest you take a look at:

- [Code: Printing a DataGrid (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287528%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Printing a DataGridView on DotNet Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridDrawer.Net.aspx)
- [Printing Selected Columns and Rows in a DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PrintDataGrid_CS.aspx)

**ORIGINAL**

Kind of confused. I think you mean "Asp.net Web Applicaion" meaning this runs in a web-browser.

So I'll answer with that in mind (if I have it backwards let me know).

The easiest C# answer is to have a separate Print.aspx page. Just put a single GridView on the page and populate it with the same data from the previous page. That way when the user prints (File->Print) they'll only get the data and not the other stuff you're trying to avoid printing.

Should also note that you can use JavaScript to invoke the print method of the browser as well, but this can't be done directly from C#.

Comment: Thanks for your support. But i want it for Windows application not for Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Why create 2 pages , just add a separate style sheet for print like :

```
<link href="/Styles/PrintStyle.css" rel=" stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

And in css

```
.NonPrintable
{
 display: none;
 }
 .NonPrintable, #Menu, #Footer 
 {
  display: none;
 }
```

You can call the css class like :

```
<body>
<input type="YouCantPrintMe" value="I am hidden" class="NonPrintable">
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I don't want to highlight the data which i want to print. I want to take printout of DataGried data.